# Serialize derived type as base type over AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, appdomain, remoting

I've got a plugin system where the plugin itself can have several runtime instances. These instances are defined with a configuration object that gets carried is made available to the plugin itself through various APIs.

The configuration contains specific parts that the parent application understands but it is expected for the plugin to specify its own parts through subclassing.

```
[Serializable]
public class PluginConfiguration {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyPluginConfiguration : PluginConfiguration {
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

This is partly technical reason as it allows the main application to just serialize the whole object as JSON/XML/etc. into database to persist both the common configuration and the plugin specific configuration.

Each plugin is hosted within its own AppDomain. However I'm getting into trouble when I'm trying to read the plugin configuration from the primary app domain and the plugin (`MarshalByRefObject` returns its `MyPluginConfiguration` object instance.

Is there a way to do some Serialization magic in the base class to ensure that the object instances are serialized as `PluginConfiguration` instances? The problem in serializing the `MyPluginConfiguration` instances are:

- The custom configuration type might not be `[Serializable]`
- Even if they were `[Serializable]`, they don't have their Assembly loaded in the primary app domain anyway.

Ideally I'd like the implementation to be restricted to the `PluginConfiguration` base class. The old `[Serializable]` semantics and AppDomains are not the most common concept in .Net and I would like to hide some of these aspects from the plugin developers if they don't need to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

Using binary serialization, per your `[Serializable]`

*Note: XML has [IXmlSerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx%20ISerializable)
and Javascript is also different. I believe JSON.net serializes ISerializable objects as implemented below*

```
[Serializable]
public class PluginConfiguration : System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PluginConfiguration()
    {

    }
    protected PluginConfiguration(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("info");
        Name = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));

    }
    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Name", Name);
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class MyPluginConfiguration : PluginConfiguration
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public MyPluginConfiguration()
    {

    }
    protected MyPluginConfiguration(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) :base(info, context)
    {

    }

}

private class PluginBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        return typeof(PluginConfiguration);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var c = new PluginConfiguration() { Name = "Name" };
var p = new MyPluginConfiguration() { Name = "Name", AccessToken = "MyToken" };

BinaryFormatter fmt = new BinaryFormatter();

MemoryStream cms = new MemoryStream();
fmt.Serialize(cms, c);

cms.Position = 0;
PluginConfiguration revc = fmt.Deserialize(cms) as PluginConfiguration;

MemoryStream pms = new MemoryStream();
fmt.Serialize(pms, p);
pms.Position = 0;
MyPluginConfiguration prev = fmt.Deserialize(pms) as MyPluginConfiguration;

//given a stream containing the serialization of MyPluginConfiguration
// serailize it as a the known PluginConfiguration Type

pms.Position = 0;
fmt.Binder = new PluginBinder();
PluginConfiguration PluginFromCustomStream = fmt.Deserialize(pms) as PluginConfiguration;
```

Comment: What I would need is `fmt.Serialize(pms,p);fmt.Deserialize(pms) as PluginConfiguration`. The plugin app domain will do the `Serialize` using the `MyPluginConfiguration` type while the application app domain won't have the `MyPluginConfiguration` available and thus can't use that for `Deserialize` so I'd need to be able to have the `Deserialize` use `PluginConfiguration` instead.

Comment: I have added a custom binder to the answer to show you how to accomplish this as well.

Comment: That sounds useful. Hadn't encountered the `SerializationBinder` type before. How do you define one for the app domains to use?

Comment: If you only want the base class to be serialized you can use the one in my example.

Comment: If `IPlugin foo` is a transparent proxy instance pointing to a plugin implmeentation in the other app domain and in the host app domain I invoke `foo.Configuration`, which is a property returning `PluginConfiguration`, the remoting infrastructure does the serialization for me. There's no manual `BinaryFormatter` involved. How do I tell the `AppDomain` instances or the transparent proxy instance that they should use my `PluginBinder` when doing the serialization when transferring `[Serializable]` objects accross the app domain boundary?